# Issue on Count of total calls

Tags: sql, firebird

On a 'CALLS' table each call has a call_start, contact_id, operator_id and so on.

I want to count the tot calls for each client on a specific weekday so I extract weekday (extract weekday from call_start) and I get 0 to 6 results.

I used a case to show weekdays (`case when (extract(weekday from call_start)=1) then 'monday'` and so on.

Now I enter `count( client_id)` and I get 2 row for 2 calls, 4 rows for 4 calls, rather than 1 row with 2 calls?

Am I missing something silly here?

I am using Firebird 1.5 by the way

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

u can try something like this

```
select
sum(case when extract(weekday from cast(call_start as date))=0 then 1 else 0 end) as qty_sun,
sum(case when extract(weekday from cast(call_start as date))=1 then 1 else 0 end) as qty_mon,
sum(case when extract(weekday from cast(call_start as date))=2 then 1 else 0 end) as qty_tue,
....
```